# Kivy: Label with text from previous screen, using ScreenManager

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have a Program, that uses ScreenManager, to switch between screens on button presses, what I want to achieve is having the label of the second screen, with a text from the previous screen's textinput, my problem seems to be that thay are in diffirent classes, i am fairly new to object programming, and therefore my question might seem stupid, the problem in my opinion is that the program dont 'run' the class every time the button is pressed, but instead just change the current widget, to the other class's widget.

Here's my code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenOne, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        my_box1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.my_label1 = TextInput(text="BlaBlaBla on screen 1", font_size='24dp')
        my_button1 = Button(text="Go to screen 2",size_hint_y=None, size_y=100)
        my_button1.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        my_box1.add_widget(self.my_label1)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_button1)
        self.add_widget(my_box1)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'

class ScreenTwo(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenTwo,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        my_box1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        my_label1 = Label(text="BlaBlaBla on screen 2",font_size='24dp')
        my_button1 = Button(text="Go to screen 1",size_hint_y=None, size_y=100)
        my_button1.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_label1)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_button1)
        self.add_widget(my_box1)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'

class TestApp(App):

        def build(self):
            my_screenmanager = ScreenManager()
            screen1 = ScreenOne(name='screen1')
            screen2 = ScreenTwo(name='screen2')
            my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen1)
            my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen2)
            return my_screenmanager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

any help apreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the managers get_screen() method and set its attributes, like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import  Label



class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenOne,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_box1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.my_label1 = TextInput(text="BlaBlaBla on scr 1", font_size='24dp')
        self.my_button1 = Button(text="Go to screen 2",size_hint_y=None, size_y=100)
        self.my_button1.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        self.my_box1.add_widget(self.my_label1)
        self.my_box1.add_widget(self.my_button1)
        self.add_widget(self.my_box1)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.get_screen("screen2").my_label1.text = self.my_label1.text  # here you set screen2's my_label1 to your input
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'




class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenTwo,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.my_box1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.my_label1 = Label(text="BlaBlaBla on screen 2",font_size='24dp')
        self.my_button1 = Button(text="Go to screen 1",size_hint_y=None, size_y=100)
        self.my_button1.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        self.my_box1.add_widget(self.my_label1)
        self.my_box1.add_widget(self.my_button1)
        self.add_widget(self.my_box1)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'



class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyApp,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = ScreenManager()

        self.sm.test = StringProperty("test")

        self.sm.add_widget(ScreenOne(name = "screen1"))
        self.sm.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name = "screen2"))


    def build(self):
        return self.sm



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: @Cid-El no problem